# TikZ & PGFPlots: adding a TikZ 3d axis into a pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.8}

\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \begin{axis}[
    samples = 1000,
    domain = -pi / 2:4 * pi,
    samples y = 0,                                                       
    no markers,
    axis lines = none
    ]
    \draw[-latex] (axis cs: 0, 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 3, 0, 0);
    \draw[-latex] (axis cs: 0, 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 3, 0);
    \draw[-latex] (axis cs: 0, 0, 0) -- (axis cs: 0, 0, 5);
    \addplot3 ({cos(deg(x))}, {sin(deg(x))}, {.5 * x});
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I have the `tdplot_main_coords` passed into `pgfplot`s so my axis isn't all crazy?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, you would like to blend stuff of `tikz-3dplot` and `pgfplots` seamlessly on top of each other. To this end, you may want to study Section "TikZ Interoperability" of the `pgfplots` manual. Note that `pgfplots` also offers the `view={<h>}{<v>}` key which allows to specify the rotation angles. I do not know if the angles are the same, but they can be transformed into each other.

Comment: Plus you can use the 3D `(axis cs:1,2,0)` syntax for drawing things in pgfplots for 3D axes.

Comment: @percusse that is what I have used to draw those lines but `pgfplots` isn't respecting `tdplotsetmaincoords`.  It has issued an entirely different rotation that isn't even the standard look without the rotation of axis.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I have tried using `view` but I still can't produce the desired results.  How would I transform my `tdplotsetmaincoords` into the corresponding `view` angles?

Comment: It seems to be as if `tikz-3dplot` angles `\tdplotsetmaincoords{h}{v}` can be transformed into those of `pgfplots` by means of `view={H}{V}` where `H=h+45`, `V=v-90`. In your case, you would have `view={115}{20}`. At least it seems so.

Comment: However, I am still unsure of what you want to archieve. Do you want to rotate a `pgfplots` axis and `tikz-3dplot` is what you have at hand? Then you may want to read the `pgfplots` manual and its associated view sections and set the manual of `tikz-3dplot` aside. Or do you want to combine `tikz-3dplot` and `pgfplots` for some reason? Then you have much more work in front of you and you should study the `pgfplots` manual section "Tikz Interoperability".

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger `view = {115}{20}` was exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.  The `-latex` arrowheads are neglected on the `x` and `y` axis.  What would cause that though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be as if `tikz-3dplot` angles `\tdplotsetmaincoords{h}{v}` can be transformed into those of `pgfplots` by means of `view={H}{V}` where `H=h+45`, `V=v-90`. In your case, you would have `view={115}{20}`. At least it seems so.

Regarding the comment why the `-latex` arrow head is ignored: I suppose it is because pgfplots has clipping active. Adding the option `clip=false` might help here (please correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: `clip = false` did it.  Also, should `60 + 45 = 105`?  Or did you mean `70 + h`?

Comment: :-D advanced summation has never been by strength (apparently). I'd say go with `105` if it looks good enough. Perhaps my rule of thumb does not fit at all; it was merely a guess (motivated by the fact that a similar heuristics appeared to work for gnuplot's view). I fear you will have to experiment until you found a good view.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative solution that doesn't use pgfplots

[image: helix]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}

\begin{document}

\tdplotsetmaincoords{60}{130}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords]
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (2,0,0) node[right] {x};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,2,0) node[left] {y};
\draw[->] (0,0,0) -- (0,0,3) node[above] {z};
\draw[thick,blue] (1,0,0)
\foreach \a in {0,0.1,...,15.71}
{ -- ({cos(deg(\a))},{sin(deg(\a)},{.10*\a})
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```